# Bordes redondeados en TabbedPage Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

He intentado cambiar el estilo de un TabbedPage para que tenga los bordes redondeados pero no lo he logrado en Xamarin Forms. Lo que intento hacer es algo como lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco de antemano cualquier solución.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega todo el código que tengas para que cualquier usuario de la comunidad pueda reproducir tu escenario :D

Comment: David, el componente no tiene la propiedad CornerRadius, y no lo he intentado pero para tener mayor control sobre los componentes de Xamarin lo que puedes hacer es utilizar representadores rapidos o CustomRenderes, te dejo el link de la doc oficial. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/index